# Is there a way that I can put the name that is in the roster in a specific cell in each google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making multiple duplicates of a Google sheet, rename the copied documents using a roster in another google sheet document, then move them all to a specified folder in my drive. Is there a way that I can put the name that is in the roster in a specific cell in each google sheet?

Comment: It it not excel question. You need AppScript coding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried, provide some sample data and be specific regarding the expected results. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Make, Move and Save Name

```
function makeSheet() {
  const ss0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh0 = ss0.getSheetByName("Roster");
  const list = sh0.getRange("A2:A" + sh0.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  list.forEach((name,i) => {
    let id = SpreadsheetApp.create(name).getId();
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0].getRange("A1").setValue(name);
    let fi = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    fi.moveTo(folder);
  })
}
```